# Overriding an OOTB component in Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to override one of the OOTB components in alfresco to modify some of its behavior, where should I place my files in the alfresco SDK2.0 project? I placed them is the web/ folder but it didn't override the default one. 
To give more details, I'm trying to override the create-content component, I placed the `create-content-mgr.css` and `create-content-mgr.js` files in the `web/components/create-content` folder, but nothing is being overridden.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your target folder to see how the asset you're generating is being distributed. Assuming you're using an amp distribution, the web folder is mapped into your target asset (and hence you webapp) based on the `file-mapping.properties` for that module.

For more information about mappings https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/AMP_Files#Customising_the_structure_of_an_AMP_file

This file should be [present in version 2.0.0 of the maven sdk](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/176). If you don't see it I would be sure you're on the correct version of the SDK. Either way you may need to modify the mappings for your specific project.

If you're overwriting an ootb asset you will need to force apply the amp.